# d3.js v4 d3.zoom and strange element order after zoom or pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I noticed a strange behavior of the d3.zoom functionality and cannot spot where in my code lies the problem. 
I have an SVG it has z-index: 900
I have a rootNode it has z-index: 100
I have surrounding nodes which have the z-index: 1000

So the SVG lines are in front of the rootNode and the surrounding nodes are in front of the rootNode and the SVG elements.

That is true but only after i panned or zoomed because then all the svg-lines are in front which doesn't make sense to me. The z-order didnt change and also the DOM didn't..

I made a fiddle showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/jxkgfdcm/

```
//create a svg in the body of index.html
var svg = container.append("svg")
  .classed("simulation", 1)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("z-index", 900);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no z-index for an SVG.

However, you can easily set the z-index of the `<div>` the SVG is in:

```
var svg = container.append("div")
    .style("z-index", 999)//z-index of the div
    .append("svg")//append the SVG to that div
    .classed("simulation", 1)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vafc312a/

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thanks for your help and it's good to know z-index won't apply to SVG. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. For example if you change the z-index of the nodes in your updated fiddle to a lower value than SVG's 999 it doesn't make them appear behind the lines. They still are in front. Only after giving a negative -1 they will be behind but then as soon as u zoom in or out or pan the graph they become in front again.. I updated you're fiddle setting z-index to -1: https://jsfiddle.net/vafc312a/1/